# Unable to read data from AJAX (dataType:"jsonp") call to web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I am using ajax call's to perform POST and GET operations from a WebService hosted on some server.

I am using dataType:"jsonp" due to the cross domain issue.I can see the data being sent by the web service on fiddler. I want to access the data which I get from the service and I dont know how do do that.

This is my ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: "url",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpcallback:function(data){},            //What am I supposed to write here so that I can get the JSON data from Padded json
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });
```

This is the approximation of the json response that I receive from the service:

```
    {"Ideas":[
               {"Message":null,"IdeaId":1},
               {"Message":null,"IdeaId":1}
             ]
    }
```

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. I searched through a lot of posts but could not get through.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually you don't need the `jsonp` or `jsonpcallback` options to send a jsonp request. Without them, what you have should work given a normal jsonp webservice. Also, the webservice needs to return the json in jsonp format rather than json. What you have above is json, not jsonp.

Comment: many API's don't support jsonp...  make sure the one you are calling does. If it is only JSON you will see the response, but browser security won't allow using it

Comment: The problem is that when I specify dataType:"json" I do not receive any response from the service. And when I specify "jsonp" I see the response being received by my local application. But the problem is it shows :200parser error even though I see json data in fiddler.I am confused and need help regarding this.

Comment: @AbhishekJ  read what I wrote closer. If API doesn't return JSONP you will have to use other methods to retrieve data.

Comment: Could you help me out with this.Since my service does not support and return "jsonp" then how do I make a successful service call without specifying the dataType as "jsonp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `jsonpcallback:function(data){},` //What am I supposed to write here so that I can get the JSON data from Padded json

Usually, nothing. You only need to specify the callback if your JSONP service is really atypical. If you do specify it, it needs to be a **string**.

Likewise you shouldn't set `jsonp: false` as that will prevent the callback parameter being generated.

You do need a success handler to handle the data though. Having an error handler is also a good idea.

```
function successHandler(data) {
    console.log(data)
}

function errorHandler(jqXHR, errorType, exception) {
    console.log(errorType, exception);
}

$.ajax({
    url: "url", // Make this the real URL!
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

Then the JSONP handler needs to actually return JSONP

The `Content-Type` header returned by the server should be `application/javascript`

The body should be:

- The value of the `callback` key in the query string
- `(`
- Some JSON
- `);`

e.g.

```
jqueryCallback123u54yiyioeuioey8({ "foo": "bar" });
```

Comment: But what if the data that I see on fiddler is of type json and not jsonp? Correct me if I am wrong. Should I be able to see the jsonp format on fiddler as well?

Comment: If the data is JSON then it is not JSONP. If it is not JSONP then you cannot load it as JSONP. You should be able to use fiddle to see whatever data is sent.

Comment: The data which is sent is json and not jsonp. But the problem is that when I specify the dataType:"json" I do not receive any response from the service(service call failed is the error). But when I specify dataType:"jsonp" I see the data in json format.Please help me with this since I have been struggling with this for a long time.

Comment: You can't make the browser fetch data from a third party site and expose it to your JavaScript without the third party site cooperating (e.g. by presenting the data as JSONP). This is a security measure to stop Joe Random site getting access to Joe Random Other site with the browser owner's credentials.

Comment: If you don't need to get the data with the user's credentials, then you can either proxy through the same origin or use another remote origin that will proxy it and re-encode the data as JSONP.

Comment: I could communicate with the service when it was hosted on my local IIS Server using dataType:"json".But when I hosted the webservice on azure cloud I could not consume the service using dataType:"json".What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Because browsers are happy to expose the data on a website to that website. If you host the data on a different website, then they restrict it to protect users. For example, it wouldn't be good if a website could use JavaScript to read the data on my bank's website … when I was logged in.

Comment: So the only option that I have is to make changes in my web service so that it supports jsonp. Am I right?

Comment: Other options include the aforementioned proxy and CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a great scripter, but I used AJAX's for my project.. Try this out, it's how it worked for me.

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: "url",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: :Hey I tried this but it did not work for me.Anyways thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your **console**. E.g. `firebug` if you use `firefox`, or `chrome's development console`.

There you should see mistakes in your code.

```
ajax()
```

function in jquery takes `success: function(data){ // do something with the data }`
callback.

```
console.log(//some data)
```

is for logging various data at different points in your script.

So

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: "url",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}

});
```

Is not such a bad idea.

Comment: Yup I did see the console on Chrome. The error being displayed is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " in the console. I thing that jquery is not able to parse the response since it expect's "jsonp" but it receives json and hence it get's confused between the 2.

Answer (score 0):

I got this up and running this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var jsonpCallback;

  function checkDocId() {
    // AJAX request
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    jsonpCallback = function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data.html);
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/secudok/ws/rest/checkdocid/jsonp/" + encodeURIComponent($("#docId").val()),
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallback",
      crossDomain: true
    });
  }

</script>
```

The server returs the data wrapped into the callback function: function({JSON}).

```
jsonpCallback({"html":"<table>data</table>\n"})
```

In my example we use HTML, but could be JSON as well

```
yourCallbackName({"a":"1"; "b":"2"})
```

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " is the error which I get when I use the above code.I think that jquery is not able to parse the response since it expect's "jsonp" but it receives json and hence it is not able to handle the json data.

Comment: I simply put the output into my container div `$("#result").html(data.html)`. What do you try to do with the response? Then I can check this.